# modification in the \cite command to show page

Tags: citing

I have a little problem.
I am using the *abntex2* package in my document, and I am using *bibtex* to make the bibliography.
When I use, for instance, *\cite{reis}*, that gives me the name of the author and the year his article was published. In this case, (REIS, 2013.) However, I need the page in which the citation was found to be between those parenthesis as well.
Is there any way I could keep using the \cite{} command and have the page appear in the document as well?

Comment: Do you mean `\cite[p. 25--31]{reis}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include the page numbers used for the cited document, then you add them as option to command `\cite`.  Say pages 25 until 31:

```
\cite[p.~25--31]{reis}
```

With `~` you can force LaTeX **not** to do a line breaking between `p.` and `25`.